# How to clip a UIImage with UIBezierPath from the previewLayer capture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, avfoundation, uibezierpath

I have a UIBezierPath created while I'm capturing a photo with AVFoundation into AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. I add a UIBezierPath in a position of the screen, and I want get the region of the photo behind this UIBezierPath.

I want get the photo like this:

I have this in the custom app camera:
[image]
And I want get this:
[image]

I'm using this code, but I can't get this, I always get the uiimage like original size and the region of the top left corner very little like this:
[image]

How can I keep the scale of original image took and only clip the region determined by the path?

This is my code, what is wrong?

```
AVCaptureConnection *connection = [stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:connection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

NSData *imageData=[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath new];
[path moveToPoint:[points[0] CGPointValue]];
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < points.count; i++)
    [path addLineToPoint:[points[i] CGPointValue]];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);

[path addClip];

[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(maskedImage, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}];
```

Comment: My guess is that the real issue is in the points array itself.  Like maybe the points are using the wrong coordinate system.  If instead of using the path to clip, you draw the image and then draw the filled (or stroked) path on top of the image, does the path appear to be in the correct position?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you give me some code or webPage with reference of this? I don't understand well.Need I save the path on independent UIIMage and then use this to mask my image?